# Read only one line with fread from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following file :

```
bla;bla;
0;1;2;3;4;
```

I want to read only the first line with fread (from data.table 1.10.0) :

`fread('data/test.txt', nrows = 1, skip = 0,
 colClasses = "character", autostart = 0, header = F)`

It produces the following warning :

```
Warning message: 
In fread("data/test.txt", nrows = 1, skip = 0, colClasses = "character",  : 
Starting data input on line 2 and discarding line 1 because it has too few or too many items to be column names or data: bla;bla;
```

Comment: You specifically want to use `fread`? How about `readLines`? Also try `fill = T` argument with `fread`.

Comment: I may use readLines if it's fast. I have a lot of files to read and first I tried read_csv2 from readr but it's much slower than fread. I'll try readLines, thanks.

Comment: I believe `fread` initially scans the file structure. While `readLines` handles file as a connection and just reads first x lines, regardless of content.

Comment: read.table solved my problems but the problem with fread is still unsolved

Comment: If you have a lot of files and only need the first line of each, maybe you should use a different tool to extract and stack those lines in a single file first, before reading into r. I guess there must be ways to do this at the command line.

Comment: `fread` is unlikely to be faster than `readLines` for reading just one line of many files due to some overhead; as Frank suggested, you're probably better off concatenating the files into a larger file via command line, then `fread`ing the output of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the present `fread` will work. The package description explicitly states

> ‘fread‘ is for regular delimited files;  i.e., where every row has the same >number of columns.  In future, secondary separator (sep2) may be specified
>   within each column.  Such columns will be read as type list where each cell >is itself a vector.

I tried the combination sep=";" and sep2=";", but that doesn't work.

With all this auto-detection going on I think some methods without auto-detection might be faster when you just want to read the first line.